# How to change the value of CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX with CMake in Windows development environmental?

Tags: cmake

I am a newbie with CMake, and recently I notice that the installation of a certain program always requires the definition of the variable CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX. For example, in the following CMake script I denote the program's install location:

```
install (TARGETS Tutorial DESTINATION bin)
```

In this script the Tutorial.exe program will be installed in the folder ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/bin. However, when I run CMake command with the denoted CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX, it fails:

```
cmake DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=c:/temp ..
```

Here I used the out-of-source CMake compiling method. I have seen several tutorials on how to use this command in LINUX environment, but not with Windows. I was wondering what's wrong with the definition of 
CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX. Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't there be a dash before the DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX?

Answer (score 1):

For Windows you can use

> cmake-gui [path to CMakeLists.txt]

In gui

- Click Configure

edit CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX to whatever you want and then

- Click Generate